# Parse.com Throttling and Server Resource Monitoring

Tags: parse-platform

Our app is experiencing an extremely high number of timeouts at times and we are fielding hundreds of inquiries from users each day. The performance of the app is intermittent - one minute running AMAZINGLY fast and the next 10 minutes, timing out non-stop. We have optimized our cloud code and when timeouts are happening, they are happening anywhere and everywhere - there is no pattern to the failure so I am lead to believe this is related to server resource issues or throttling. Is there anyway to gain insights into throttling or server performance / resource usage?

Comment: Throttling would be obvious, as errors with code 141 would be returned.  I suggest opening a bug report at developers.facebook.com.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about the throttling error code - definitely not seeing any 141 errors in the logs so that should rule out throttling. I've opened a support ticket but it doesn't seem to get me in touch with any server admin who might be able to provide some insight about resources so I thought I would post here to see if anyone had a surefire way to get insight into server performance.